# How to properly rewrite URL in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I have one public IP and I need to maintain two web servers, therefore I've decided to make reverse proxy server. My proxy server uses NGNIX, and back end one uses Apache.

10.1.1.3 is Nginx's ip

10.1.1.5 is Apache's ip

I want to have one application available at domain.com/project and the other one at domain.com/application2

I try to keep nginx's configuration as simple as possible as I'm still learning:

```
server{ 
     listen 80;

     location /project {
         rewrite /project / break;
         proxy_pass http://10.1.1.5:80;
     }
}
```

I'm trying to make it possible to access project application on Apache web server, but the problem is that project application doesn't have url 10.1.1.50:80/project so I try to rewrite it. It works, I can access the server writing in domain.com/project but if I try to enter any link for example account creation it changes link to domain.com/account/register, and proxy server requires domain.com/project/account/register to work. Is it possible to preserve project part of URI for any further requests?

Comment: You need to tell the application what is the base URL it is working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
server{ 
     listen 80;
     server_name domain.com;
     location ~ ^/project?(.*) 
     {
            proxy_pass http://10.1.1.5:80$1$is_args$args;
     }
}
```

Probably you need something like this.